# Pinterest and dynamic content

Tags: ajax, dynamic, pinterest

Due to the server provider I'm forced to use, some pages of our site have to created dynamically with ajax. So the content area of the page is blank on initial load, and filled with content after a few moments.

Now, when someone tries to scrape images of the site with Pinterest's "Add from a website" -tool, nothing shows up. Are there any workarounds for this in the Pinterest API? Some header tags etc that would make Pinterest wait for a moment before scraping?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Structured Meta Data and applied and were approved for [Rich Pins](http://business.pinterest.com/en/rich-pins) it might help, but you can never predict the timing of robots. I've seen a day or more go by before a Pinterest button credits a pin and I've seen it happen instananeously on the same campaign page.

Pinterest reserves the right to turn you down for Rich Pins and or just take their sweet time reviewing your applications. Rich Pins is not as big of win as Twitter Cards but it is probably worth doing if your target audience is 70% Midwestern housewives.

Comment: Using rich pins was a bit overkill for this. I ended up adding individual Pin it -links dynamically over the images.

Comment: You can do whatever you like, it was just a suggestion. If you solved this problem you should write up your solution and mark it closed.